# set focus to JList and have cursor on textField swing java autocomplete

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtextfield, jlist

I started to develop my own auto complete swing component and I want to set focus to the list when user press up or down keys and in the same time let the cursor on the textfield to allow him to type text or number....

to set focus to JList when typing up or down I have used

list.requestFocus();

is there any way to have focus on JList and cursor on JTextField

please view the image in [here](http://s8.postimg.org/lmzxmwa8x/Capture.png)

here my code :

```
    package examples.autocomplete;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.gestioncaisse.dao.ClientDAO;
import com.gestioncaisse.dao.DAO;
import com.gestioncaisse.dao.MyConnection;
import com.gestioncaisse.pojos.Client;
import com.gestioncaisse.utils.utils;

public class testcombo extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    final DAO<Client> clientDao;
    List<Client> list_clients;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testcombo frame = new testcombo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    boolean first_time = true;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public testcombo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        clientDao = new ClientDAO(MyConnection.getInstance());

        list_clients = clientDao.findAll();

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(5, 11, 113, 20);

        textField.setColumns(10);

        final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("...");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(116, 10, 45, 23);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(5, 31, 156, 144);

        final JList list = new JList(
                utils.fromListToObjectTable2Clients(list_clients));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);

        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                int a = list.getSelectedIndex();
                if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    list.requestFocus();
                } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    list.requestFocus();
                } else if (!first_time) {
                } else {
                    first_time = false;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }
        });

    }
}

//if (a > 0)
//list.setSelectedIndex(a - 1);
//int first_vis = list.getFirstVisibleIndex();
//list.setListData(utils.fromListToObjectTable2Clients(clientDao.findByString(textField.getText())));
//list.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Post code, which you try to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the focus on the `JTextField` but add [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to the UP/DOWN key. In the actions just change selection in `JList` (`public void setSelectedIndex(int index)` method)

UPDATE

An aslternative way would be to have focus on JList and add KeyListener translating typed chars to the JTextField. To Show caret use

```
jTextFieldInstance.getCaret().setVisible(true);
jTextFieldInstance.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
```

Comment: I have tried setSelectedIndex but it is less convenient and less quick and in that case I have also to make visible selected items if they aren't which I didn't know also

Comment: @user3747935 JList has built_in navigation (KeyBindings), e.g. twice to press any char, sure works only for 1st. char in String (startWith)

Comment: then, you may say, that is impossible to have what I want ??

Comment: @user3747935 autocomplete with logics Database v.s. JTextField isn't possible to create without Workers Thread, this question doesn't make me sence, description talking about JList, code about something that is against all rulles, use DocumentListener for JTextCOmponents, otherwise there is 4-5 basics requirents foír input field that isn't possible to listening from KeyListener added to JTextField (plus issue with selection v.s action, copy_paste from clipboard)

Comment: @grotibo I don't care in this thread what do you may or want to do, this is thread by another user or (correct me if am I wrong)???

Comment: @grotibo question is if is there autocomplete against database or Jlist, both are based on very different solution(s)

Comment: when user type on textfield I request database to get matched data and set data to JList, that is all

Answer (score 2):

Here i used to retrieve matched data from database

```
   keywordssearcher.setEditable(true);
    final JTextComponent sfield = (JTextComponent)    keywordssearcher.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    sfield.setVisible(true);
    sfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    comboFilter(sfield.getText(), con);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (!(sfield.getText().equals("")) || (sfield.getText() == null)) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    addKeyWord(sfield.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });

  public void comboFilter(String enteredText, Connection ncon) {
    log.info("ncon autosuggest--->" + ncon);
    ArrayList<String> filterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str1 = "";
    try {
        Statement stmt = dc.ConnectDB().createStatement();
        String str = "SELECT k_word FROM T_KeyWords WHERE k_word LIKE '" + enteredText + "%'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while (rs.next()) {
            str1 = rs.getString("k_word");
            filterArray.add(str1);
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error in getting keywords from database" + ex.toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in getting keywords from database" + ex.toString());
    }

    if (filterArray.size() > 0) {
        keywordssearcher.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
        keywordssearcher.setSelectedItem(enteredText);
        keywordssearcher.showPopup();
    } else {
        keywordssearcher.hidePopup();
    }
}
```

Here my keywordssearcher(jcombobox) is editable and the entered value can be added directly into the database.

use this as a reference and modify the code

Comment: I want to create my own component because I have my own specifications and I don't have problem with retrieving data ...., the only problem I have is this one